# Data storage solutions for rapidly running out of space

Tags: linux, hosting, storage, cloud-computing

I have 2 web servers (1 live and other backup), the issue I have is our storage is rapidly running out.

All the data on the server is used by our customers and new documents are uploaded to the server daily. So nothing can be deleted as it's always in use. We use a flat file structure with no database.

I'm seeking solutions or ideas for the best place to move the our data to. The data has to be secure and needs to run on a linux environment.

Not sure where to start - clusters, vmware, or they such solutions for huge file servers?

Comment: What are you storing? What are your requirements? See @Chopper3's answer below...

Answer (score 5):

Forget about the technology, this is a process issue for now, let technology fix the problem at the right point. Right now you have a situation that you see to have little control of, let alone ability to influence within supportable time-frames. What you need to to is plan, set rules and ensure they're adhered to.

For instance what's the 'glide path' for growth? do you know how much it's growing per day/week/month/quarter etc.? If not then how can you possibly size things correctly regardless of what you use?

Do customers assume you're backing this all up? if so why and are you? how long can you keep it up if you are?

This is about control, you need to take it and keep it - everything else is just budget and a bit of technical work. Come back when you've got to that point and have far lower level questions to ask and we'll be happy to help. Oh and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is disk space, add more disks.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the option of an extendable DAS box. Those can also usually be cascaded, to add more boxes. 
All you need in the host is a raid controller or a SAS/SCSI HBA with an external connector.